# NuGet in a sub-repo (externals) environment

Tags: mercurial, nuget, mercurial-subrepos

I have a few repositories in Mercurial with the following structure:

- Core
- Integration
- Admin
- MyApp

From the `MyApp` repo, I want to include `Core` and `Integration`.

I add those as a sub-repo to `MyApp`, and place it inside an `Externals` folder.

Folder structure for `MyApp` looks roughly as this:

MyApp
 - BusinessLogic
 - DataAccess
 - Externals
 -- Core
 -- Integration
 - Web
 - packages

The problem has got to do with the `packages` folder. I use package restore in all solutions, and NuGet downloads all packages fine. The folder contains the packages that my external projects rely on.

Only problem is, that the relative path from `Core` and `Integration` to the packages folder is now wrong.

Is there any way I can solve this?

Comment: Do you use Externals only in one solution or in many?

Comment: In many. The `Integration` project have the `Core` project as a subrepo. `Core` will most likely be added to most other repos.

Comment: Sorry, but can you clarify, do you clone Core `Core` subrepo to each repo (solution) or store only one copy of `Core` and link it to many solutions?

Comment: I clone it as a subrepo in every repo I need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can fix it manually, your references should have relative hint path which starts with `../../packages`. But to avoid this in future **All** you solutions which include this projects must have the same structure.
For example for other solution you have structure like:

```
MyOtherApp
- BusinessLogic
- DataAccess
- Externals
-- SubFolder
--- Core
--- Integration
- Web
- packages
```

If in this case you add nuget package to Core project, reference will be `../../../packages/...`. And `Core` will be broken in other solutions again.

Other solution is make package from `Core` and `Integration` projects and use them in other solutions via nuget. My team uses for this TeamCity, it can pack projects, publish nuget packages and work as nuget feed out the box.

Comment: That would work, but only when the `Core` and `Integration` projects are opened as an external. This will stop working if I open the solution directly.

Comment: Better solution which based on Nuget idea - make package from your `Core` and `Integration` projects and use it in other solutions as nuget packages

Comment: Yes, I've actually taken that route and are dumping externals/subrepos since they add more confusion.

Comment: Change your answer to something about Nu Get, and I'll mark it as the answer and you get the points.

Comment: I'm already using TeamCity, so a private Nu Get feed was a no-brainer :)

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to keep it as a sub-repository (as opposed to referencing the projects as NuGet packages) you can modify the the hint paths to always search the solution directory.

For instance, I changed

```
<HintPath>..\..\packages\Moq.4.2.1312.1622\lib\net40\Moq.dll</HintPath>
```

to

```
<HintPath>$(SolutionDir)packages\Moq.4.2.1312.1622\lib\net40\Moq.dll</HintPath>
```